# I can't find any plantera bulbs in terraria even though im on hardmode

Tags: terraria-mobile

I can't find any plantera bulbs even though I'm in hardmode.
I'm playing Terraria on Android.

Comment: Where are you searching for the bulbs?

Comment: in the underground jungle

Answer (score 5):

To summon Plantera you need to destroy a **Plantera's Bulb** which spawns every half a day in Terraria, however, they will not spawn unless all three mechanical bosses have been defeated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find any **Plantera Bulbs**, try waiting half a day. After that, go back to the jungle and look at your map and look for a 2x2 pink pixel  and you'll probably find a **Plantera Bulb**. Keep in mind that the *Mechanical Bosses* must be defeated beforehand.